# connecting ipads to a windows domain

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, security, domain, ipad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iPad Management](https://serverfault.com/questions/186666/ipad-management)

Do iPads (version 1, 2, and/or 3) have the ability to connect to a windows server 2008 or 2008 R2 domain?

If not, is there a way to enforce security settings from a central location, rather than configuring each one individually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are management tools built into OS X server as well as third party tools from companies like JAMF and Absolute. There is no windows-native solution for what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

Afaik you cannot join those devices to a Windows AD.

You can, however, manage them centrally with some management tools like [MobileIron](http://www.mobileiron.com/en/multi-os-management/ios-management/overview) which I heard lots of good things about.

Answer (score 1):

Novell zenworks has mobile managment software, but that costs money and i'm not sure how much managment it gives with ipad. quick google search found this

https://blogs.dirteam.com/blogs/sanderberkouwer/archive/2011/06/04/centralized-ipad-management-with-profiles-and-policies.aspx